# How to get text in white color from image in grey background and paste it on another image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Hi I am using opencv to extract text in white from one image and paste it on another. I am using below approach for black image background and it works fine. Check the below code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image_msg = (30, 209, 187, 31)

base_path="/Users/images/"
mask_image1 = "{}show_image_2.PNG".format(base_path)

image_1_title = "{}show_image_2_logo.PNG".format(base_path)

img = cv2.imread(mask_image1)


image_1_title_img = cv2.imread(image_1_title)
image_1_titl_img = cv2.cvtColor(image_1_title_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im1r_title = cv2.resize(image_1_titl_img, (image_msg[2], image_msg[3]))

print(im1r_title.shape)
plt.imshow(im1r_title,cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
print(img.shape)
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

img[image_msg[1]: image_msg[1] + image_msg[3], 
      image_msg[0]: image_msg[0] + image_msg[2],
     ] = np.where(im1r_title < [100, 100, 100], img[image_msg[1]: image_msg[1] + image_msg[3], 
     image_msg[0]: image_msg[0] + image_msg[2],
     ], im1r_title)

plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Result:

[image]

however I am struggling to find a way to get the text in white color from the below, if you open this image you will see text in white, how can I extract and paste on another image?

Problematic image with text:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because all the information is actually in the alpha/transparency channel which shows where white should show and where the black background should show.

If I separate your image into its constituent R,G,B and A channels and lay them out side-by-side you will see the info is in the A channel on the right:

[image]

I artificially added a red border so you can see its full extent on StackOverflow's pesky white background.

You will need to open it with:

```
im = cv.imread(..., cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[..., 3]
```

Comment: thanks I read it the way you suggested and converted it to RGB and was able to extract text in the way that I posted in question.

Answer (score 0):

I need bigger poster such as 1280 x 841.

The logo poster is wider than move poster. So it cannot fix inside move poster.

So, I substituted movie poster into Ralph's photo.

Don't need to extract text. The `OpenCV` will do.

- Add cv2.threshold.
- Add cv2.bitwise_not
- Add cv2.bitwise_and
- You can change 550 any number to suit you need.

Snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('ralph.jpg')
overlay_img1 = np.ones(img1.shape,np.uint8)*255

img2 = cv2.imread('logo.png')
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
overlay_img1[550:rows+550, 550:cols+550 ] = img2

img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(overlay_img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray,220,55,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
temp1 = cv2.bitwise_and(img1,img1,mask = mask_inv)
temp2 = cv2.bitwise_and(overlay_img1,overlay_img1, mask = mask)

result = cv2.add(temp1,temp2)
cv2.imshow("Result",result)
cv2.imwrite("Result.jpg",result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but i am struggling with the troubling image with grey background